# Mutating Vuex array that is used in different component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In first component I have a function that changes the array using the value that is stored in VueX

```
 methods: {
    //get a function that changes the pickedlist array that is stored in vuex store
    ...mapActions([ 
      'updatePickedDates'
      ]),
    ...mapGetters([
      'dates'
    ]),
    resetArray() {
      this.updatePickedDates(this.dates}
 }
```

In another component

I use getter from VueX that is passed on this array:

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["managementNews"])
  }
```

However when `resetArray()` function runs I get error that
`state.pickedDates.includes is not a function`

Here are the getters and mutations in my VueX store:

```
 mutations: {
    mutatePickedDates: (state, payload) => {
      state.pickedDates=payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updatePickedDates({commit}, payload) {
      commit('mutatePickedDates', payload)
    }
  },
  modules: {
  },
  getters : {
    //get news that are of type management
    managementNews: function(state) {
      return state.news.filter(i => i.type === "management" && state.pickedDates.includes(i.date));
    },
    dates: state => {
      return state.dates
    },
    pickedDates: state => {
      return state.pickedDates
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `this.dates` is a function and not an array. The error indicates that it's not undefined, yet it doesn't have `includes` method.

`mapGetters` should provide getters for computed properties. There's no way how  `mapGetters` could be applied to `methods` and make `this.dates` to be an array.

It should be:

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([ 
      'updatePickedDates'
    ])
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'dates'
    ]),
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I was also thinking about creating a method in vuex however not sure if this can be written as getter method? or maybe something like setter?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, if you need a setter, that's a case for mutation, and that's what you already did in mutatePickedDates. If you use resetArray more than once, consider writing it as Vuex mutation, too.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about using setter for resetArray however its only one time I use this function so I guess it is not that neccessary?

Comment: I think it's not. Notice that unidirectional data flow with `map*` helpers alone is the preferred way to do this in Vuex, that's where it borrows from Redux. You can achieve this with two-way flow and getter-setter pairs but this may be bulkier and scatters the logic between Vuex and components, e.g. https://itnext.io/anyway-this-is-how-to-use-v-model-with-vuex-computed-setter-in-action-320eb682c976